# There are 51 houses on a street. (counting problem)

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

There are 51 houses on a street. Each house has an address
between 1000 and 1099, inclusive. Show that at least two
houses have addresses that are consecutive integers.

Comment: Pigeon Hole Principle...

Comment: @OP Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prove this by contradiction. Suppose there are no pairs of houses with consecutive integers. Then we can consider the couples
$$ (n,n+1) $$
where $n$ is the number of a house and $n+1\leq 1099$. We have $50$ of those couples, and by hypothesis they don't intersect. But this implies there are
$$ 50\cdot 2 = 100 $$
different numbers between $1000$ and $1099$, which is absurd.